# Large Zend_Db query

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there a better way to accomplish the following?

```
/**
 * Performs an access check given a user.
 *
 * @param Cas_Acl_Sid $user The user or SID being checked.
 * @param Cas_Acl_Privilege $privilege The privilege to check.
 * @return int|null 1 if user access allowed, 2 if group access allowed, false if access is denied, null if access cannot be determined.
 */
public function accessCheck(Cas_Acl_Sid $user, Cas_Acl_Privilege $privilege)
{
    $db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
    $usersQuery = $db->select()->from('AccessControlEntries', array('Allowed', new Zend_Db_Expr('1 AS Type')))
        ->where('Acl = ?', $this->_id)
        ->where('Sid = ?', $user->GetGuid())
        ->where('Privilege = ?', $privilege->GetId());

    $groupsQuery = $db->select()->from('AccessControlEntries', array('Allowed', new Zend_Db_Expr('2 AS Type')))
        ->join('GroupMembers', $db->quoteIdentifier(array('GroupMembers', 'Group')) . ' = ' .
                               $db->quoteIdentifier(array('AccessControlEntries', 'Sid')), array())
        ->where('Acl = ?', $this->_id)
        ->where($db->quoteIdentifier(array('GroupMembers', 'User')) . ' = ?', $user->GetGuid())
        ->where('Privilege = ?', $privilege->GetId());

    $query = $db->select()
        ->union(array($usersQuery, $groupsQuery), Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION_ALL)
        ->order('Type')
        ->order('Allowed')
        ->limit(1);

    $dbResult = $db->fetchAll($query);

    if (!count($dbResult))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        if ($dbResult[0]['Allowed'])
        {
            return (int)$dbResult[0]['Type'];
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you supply a basic schema of the tables involved?

Comment: Any reason your method starts with an uppercase letter? This is against Zend coding standards. I always follow the convention of the framework I'm using, even if I don't like it.

Comment: @Cobby: I was not aware there was a convention on this. (Doesn't matter much now, as I've thrown Zend by the wayside a long time ago now, thank <insert deity>)

Comment: I'm a big fan of Zend Framework, but Zend_Db wasn't a very good library. That being said, it was still a good move changing from Zend Framework; given that PHP v5.3+ frameworks are wayy better.

Comment: @Cobby: Well, really, what I did was dump PHP itself :)

Comment: @BillyONeal Yea, probably a good move too. PHP is really starting to show it's age in between all the new features.

Answer (score 2):

### Stored procedure

The query above is enough big to move it from the application layer to the database in the form of a stored procedure. It will be clearer and faster, the only disadvantage is that an SP has a hard dependency on the database type (MySQL, MSSQL, other).

### Return value(s)

You are returning 3 types in your method: null, integer and boolean.
Keep your logic clean, and return always one type if you can (yes, PHP has it's type juggling "issue" but still, clean code talks).

```
public function accessCheck(Cas_Acl_Sid $user, Cas_Acl_Privilege $privilege)
{
    //execute the query in a stored procedure

    $dbResult = // stored procedure result

    if (empty($dbResult) || !$dbResult[0]['Allowed'])
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return (int)$dbResult[0]['Type'];
}
```

Comment: If you can accept a hard dependency on a single database type, there's little reason to use Zend_Db at all. As for faster, there is little evidence of that. As for returning different types; the value `0` is a valid primary key value, so your "return 0" example above is not correct.

Comment: In most cases the primary key seed is 1 so 0 is invalid. Second if you are dealing with an ACL problem, then the valid values should be the nth power of second: 1, 2, 4, 8 and so on plus the 0. Why? You can apply a logical and to get who can read or write something ( if ($result & WRITE) { /* can write */ } ). If the result is 0 then the if statement will be false.

Comment: Only if you can represent all your permissions in a bit field.